# Ruby on Rails View Rendering DB Info On Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a project and currently working on one of the views which is a page of different categories. Everything is rendering correctly however it's also putting the db info in the page.

Here is the code of my view

```
<div class="categories">
    <div class="container blurbs">
        <div class="cards row">
            <%= @categories.each do |c| %>
            <div class="card col-xs-4" %>
                <%= image_tag c.image, :class => "cat" %>
                <h4 class="title"><%= c.title %></h4>
            </div>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a link to a 
[screenshot of rendered page](https://sjconfections.tinytake.com/sf/MTcwOTAzXzEwODEzOTk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, fix is:

```
<div class="categories">
    <div class="container blurbs">
        <div class="cards row">
            <% @categories.each do |c| %>
            <div class="card col-xs-4" %>
                <%= image_tag c.image, :class => "cat" %>
                <h4 class="title"><%= c.title %></h4>
            </div>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Look I removed `=` from this `<%=`.. In the below line :

```
<% @categories.each do |c| %>
```

`#each` method returns the collection after it completed its iterations. And due to this `<%=`, the return value of `each` which is `@categories` printed back. But if you use `<%..` only, all above things will happen, but it wouldn't print back the object `@categories`.

Comment: That did the trick. Crazy how a little thing like an equals sign can throw the whole thing off. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

when you use the tags `<%= ... %>` whatever is within the tags gets displayed on the page. In your current view you have

```
<%= @categories.each do |c| %>
  <div class="card col-xs-4" %>
    <%= image_tag c.image, :class => "cat" %>
    <h4 class="title"><%= c.title %></h4>
  </div> 
<% end %>
```

Which displays the entirety of whatever the loop returns which is where you're getting the display. Change the tags to be `<% @categories.each do |c| %>` and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the explanation about the use of <%=  ...  %>